# Accessing functions across threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, textbox, backgroundworker

I am working on a program which uses a `backgroundWorker` to append text to a `Textbox` control. My problem is that simply, the `backgroundWorker` will not insert text into the `Textbox` control, it just remains blank.

My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); //Start the worker
}

public void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
    this.writeText("Hello World!");
}

public void writeText(string text) {
    textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text + text + "\r\n";
    textbox1.SelectionStart = textbox1.Text.Length;
    textbox1.ScrollToCaret();        //Scroll to the end of the textbox
}
```

Looking at the code, it seems fine (to me anyway) and it compiles fine too, so it's probably something very obvious that I am missing.

If someone would care to enlighten me on what I am doing wrong, it would be much appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a delegate at the class level for your Form.

```
public delegate void WriteLogEntryDelegate(string log_entry);
```

You can then wrap up most of the logic in another method:

```
void WriteLogEntryCB(string log_entry)
    {
        if (textbox1.InvokeRequired == true)
                {
                    var d = new WriteLogEntryDelegate(WriteLogEntryCB);
                    this.Invoke(d, log_entry);
                }
                else
                {
                    textbox1.Text(log_entry + "\r\n");
                    this.textbox1.SelectionStart = this.textbox1.Text.Length;
                    this.textbox1.ScrollToCaret();
                }
    }
```

You can then call that Function from your DoWork Method:

```
public void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) 
{
    WriteLogEntryCB("Hello World!");
}
```

Edit to Include Daniel Mann's Suggestion:
Another way would be to cast the sender in the DoWork method as the BackgroundWorker, and then call the ReportProgress Method (or use the RunWorkerCompleted Event Handler).

```
void bw1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        worker.ReportProgress((1));
    }
```

You would then require an event handler for the ProgressChanged Event:

```
void bw1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //update textbox here
    }
```

Finally, you could also use the RunWorkerCompleted Event Handler:

```
void bw1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       //update textbox here
    }
```

Comment: No Problem; Daniel Mann also points out another way of getting back to the UI thread. I will edit my post with some example code

Comment: While this may work, it's *not* a good approach, and is counter to how the `BackgroundWorker` class operates. The `BackgroundWorker` class has functionality built in to allow you to report progress back to the UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

In the method subscribed to the `DoWork` event, do your long-running operation. Then, within the worker method, you can call `ReportProgress` to send updates. This causes the `OnProgressChanged` event to fire on your UI thread, at which time you can make changes to your UI.

Alternately, if you're on .NET 4.5, you could use the async/await pattern to keep your UI responsive while performing long-running, I/O-bound operations. For CPU-bound operations, a `BackgroundWorker` is still appropriate.

As always, MSDN is a fantastic resource. From the [`BackgroundWorker` page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> To set up for a background operation, add an event handler for the
>   DoWork event. Call your time-consuming operation in this event
>   handler. To start the operation, call RunWorkerAsync. To receive
>   notifications of progress updates, handle the ProgressChanged event.
>   To receive a notification when the operation is completed, handle the
>   RunWorkerCompleted event.
>
> You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in
>   your DoWork event handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface
>   through the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events.

Answer (score 0):

In the writeText method, the UI related code should be invoked by the UI

thread that create the UI controls.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is called attempt to get access to the UI element from other the thread rather than the thread where element was created.

Read more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx).